# Error c# .net Operation must use an updateable query

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Error is there in cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();

```
for(int i=0; i<listView1.Items.Count;i++)
{
    string query2 = "INSERT INTO OrderItems(Order_ID,Item_ID,OI_Quantity,Unit_Price) values ('"+Convert.ToInt32(textBoxId.Text)+"','"+Convert.ToInt32(this.listView1.Items[i].SubItems[5].Text.ToString())+"','"+Convert.ToInt32(this.listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text.ToString())+"','"+Convert.ToInt32(this.listView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text.ToString())+"')";
    OleDbCommand cmd2= new OleDbCommand(query2,con);
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

    string query3 = "UPDATE Item set stock=(select stock from Item where ID='" + Convert.ToInt32(this.listView1.Items[i].SubItems[5].Text.ToString()) + "') - '" + Convert.ToInt32(this.listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text.ToString()) + "' where ID='" + Convert.ToInt32(this.listView1.Items[i].SubItems[5].Text.ToString()) + "' ";
    OleDbCommand cmd3 = new OleDbCommand(query3, con);
    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: What is your connection string ?

Comment: What is in query3 after assignment?

Comment: I have used connection string above the code
no problem with connection

Comment: Print out the query an try it in ssms.  Why are you creating two cmd in a loop? Just create on command and use it in the loop.  stock=(select stock can return zero or many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are performing minus operation with in update query where parameters are bounded in '' quotes, which sql doesn't take as integer.

You can store result of minus operation in a variable and then use that variable in update query.